# Cannot get rid of two DNS servers on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dns

I've got an issue with my registered DNS server on Windows 10, I cannot get rid of 2 of them. To give a quick view of what's wrong, here is my ipconfig /all output :

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : mercredi 6 septembre 2017 14:35:59
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : jeudi 7 septembre 2017 02:39:11
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 211.99.143.33
                                    58.30.131.33
                                    8.8.8.8
                                    8.8.4.4
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

As you can see, I've got 4 DNS servers registered, the two last one (Google's ones) are how I succeed to still access the web, I added them through the UI in the Ipv4 Network properties.
However, I would like to understand where the two first IPs are stored and how I can get rid of them. Those IPs are from Chinese ISP "China Telecom".

I went to China recently and had to install two VPN software (Astrill and ExpressVPN) and I feel the issue is coming from those. However, I will still need a VPN software later and I would like to know how I can deal with the DNS without uninstalling my VPNs each time.

Thanks for your help!
Corentin

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. It's hard to read, doesn't scale, can't be copy-pasted and doesn't work at all with screen readers. Please [edit] your post and include `ipconfig` output, you can copy-paste from your `cmd` window. Select pasted text and press `Ctrl+K`, it will be formatted nicely.

Comment: Did you already checked the advanced button where you added the Google dns ip's? Advanced => DNS tab => add or remove.

Comment: @maxim Didn't know about that and just found these two addresses hidden there! Thanks!

Comment: @maxim can you please make an answer so I can accept it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to find out more configured DNS servers on your Win 10 pc go to your network connection properties. Tcp/ip4 => properties => Advanced => DNS tab => add or remove.